# Visual Studio 2015 debugger becomes unstable after using OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 and have recently begun to experience a problem when using the `OpenFileDialog` control.  I can run a debugging session on my program two or three times and use `OpenFileDialog` without problems.  After that, whenever I close the main form, the debugger does not terminate.  Clicking on the "Stop Debugging" button has no effect for about 20 seconds and then I get a `messagebox`:

The debugger was unable to terminate one or more processes.

> [9408] .....vshost.exe: Access is denied.
>
> The debugger may be unstable now.  It is recommended that you save all files and exit.

After closing this box, the system again hangs for quite a while before returning to the code editor.

In the Immediate Window is the message:

> Exception thrown at 0x752F3E28 (KernelBase.dll) in WindowsApplication1.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.

In the Output Window under "Diagnostics Hub" is the message:

> Invalid operation detected by >'StandardClientTransportConnection.SendCustomMessage'.

Following advice in posts with similar problems, I have used `Autoruns.exe` to disable ALL explorer extensions.  This has not solved the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am now satisfied that the problem was caused by an incompatibility between the anti-virus product and the VS Debugger.  It may be pure coincidence, but there exists another product called "Device Monitoring Studio" which documents an Interface/Method "IConnection.SendCustomMessage", so perhaps this and the AV product are related in some way.

Answer (score -1):

You can try creating the OpenFileDialog at runtime. With a using block the object will be disposed automatically. This may do a better job cleaning up its resources than the persistent control on your form.

```
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
    ofd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ' user chose a file
    Else
        ' user canceled out
    End If
End Using ' the ofd object is disposed
```

Comment: Thanks, Verdolino, I did try that before posting this question.  I think I have now found the cause of the problem.  I have uninstalled McAfee AV and replaced it with another.  So far, I have not had any further issues.